# To read and process data from edit text

Tags: android

I'm new to android. I've an activity which consists of radio buttons, and on pressing each button it opens another activity which consists of `EditText` and`TextView`. The number of `EditText` and `TextViews` may vary according to each button press. I want to read data from all `EditText` and process it(like adding etc). The input to `EditText` is only integers.

For example on pressing a button an activity gets created with 5 `EditText` views. I want to add all the numbers that are entered to each `EditText`.
How can I do this?

Comment: add your code here .

Answer (score 1):

You can get the input from edittext like

```
int a = Integer.parseInt(edittext.getText().toString());
```

Do this for all edittext you have in your currently activity. And then perform further action as needed in those integers.
You can set the output to textview like

```
textview.setText(someVar);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you will have to do is get all the edittext value convert it to integer and add it. 
Example would be:
lets say you have 3 edittexts.

```
private editText1,editText2,editText3;
private Button sum;

//on button click event do this
sum.setOnClickListener(view.OnClickListener(){
public void onClick(View v){
 int a = Integer.parseInt(editText1.getText().toString());
 int b = Integer.parseInt(editText1.getText().toString());
 int c = Integer.parseInt(editText1.getText().toString());

//add these numbers
 int totalSum = inta+intb+inc;
```

//Show the value in toast

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),String.valueOf(totalSum),Toast.LENGTH_LONG),show();
}
});
```